# Get Required Variables From A Twig Template

Tags: templates, variables, twig

I'm new with Twig and i need function, which tests if all required variables in a Twig templates are set in an array
I searched for a method to get all variables from a twig template, but it seems that this does not exist.

Is there any good solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

The special `_context` variable contains all variables available in your template.

If you *manually* want to check what's inside, use:

```
{{ dump(_context) }}
```

If you *automatically* want to check if your variables exists, you can do something like (if your variables are `a`, `b`, `c`):

```
{% _context|keys|sort|join(',') == 'a,b,c' %}
```

See the [demo](http://twigfiddle.com/jej2o2)

Answer (score 0):

Mayby this function help you - dump()
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html
If you work with Symfony you must have this function by default. 
But if you have only a Twig the dump function is not available by default and You must add the Twig_Extension_Debug extension.

Comment: But than i have to use the dump function for every single variable, right?

Comment: If you want see all var in your template use empty parentheses - dump()